# chaning ip addresses within Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I set up Kubernetes on ubuntu with one master and two worker nodes. I use the IPv4 subnet 192.168.2.0/24 to define ip addresses for the master and nodes.

So, the kube-api server talks via 192.168.2.108 to the nodes on that subnet.

Now, I would like to change the subnet within the cluster to 192.168.50.0/24. What kind of options do I have to achieve that?

Is this possible anyway?

Thx 
aracloud

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the subent for pods and services to the kube-controller during start up.

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-controller-manager/

```
--service-cluster-ip-range string
--cluster-cidr string
```

Will set the virtual IP range for services and pods respectivley.
Worker nodes will inherit pod range from the master.